# navigationBarHidden broken with SwiftUI Xcode beta?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying out SwiftUI for an demo project and my `navigationBarHidden` fails on one computer while succeeding on another. They are both on the Xcode Beta.

It is a very simple transit app with a tab bar and navigation view as its root. The detail view has a custom header with floating buttons for backward navigation as well as a "more" menu. I want to hide the navigation bar to make this as visually appealing as possible, but right now I can't get the nav bar to disappear one one of my machines.

```swift
struct Dashboard: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView {
                SavedStopsBrowser().tabItem {
                    Label(Verbiage.shared.saved, systemImage: "star")
                }
                StopSearcher().tabItem {
                    Label(Verbiage.shared.search, systemImage: "magnifyingglass")
                }
            }.accentColor(AppColors.primary)
        }
    }
}
```

The detail view of the saved stop is as such:

```swift
struct StopViewer: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation
    let stop: TrainStop
    
    init(stop: TrainStop) {
        self.stop = stop
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    CollapseableStopHeader(stop: stop, geometry: geometry, backButtonAction: {
                        self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }, moreButtonAction: {
                        print("User did press more button")
                    })
                    TransitLineCatalog(lines: stop.associatedTrainLines)
                        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 8, bottom: 0, trailing: 10))
                }
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .top)
        }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts or suggestions as a way to make this work? Am I doing something horribly wrong?

Comment: I think there is an issue. `navigationTitle` is also acting up. It doesnt appear in iOS 15 but is fine in iOS 14

Comment: For me `.navigationBarHidden(true)` does not work when using `.navigationViewStyle(.stack)` in iOS 14 b4 and b5. I didn't try earlier betas.

Comment: I'm seeing the same on iOS 15 beta 5. It doesn't happen in iOS 14. I'm hoping beta 6 will fix it.

Comment: Seems to be still an issue in RC1.

Comment: Any one found a solution? we need to use `.navigationViewStyle(.stack)` as we support iPad too.